# How does this line of code work? AFNetworking/CFURLCopyPassword

Tags: objective-c, ios, authentication, afnetworking

How does this line of code work?

I am trying to modify the URL for this to work, but from looking at the Apple Documentation it doesn't give much on where I should put the password/URL.

```
 NSString *password = [(NSString *)CFURLCopyPassword((CFURLRef)[self.request URL]) autorelease];
```

This line of code is part of the AFNetworking framework so I can pass authentication.

How is the URL suppose to be structured for this to grab the password correctly? I have no luck with it yet.

I tried putting it in the front username:password, but that is not right. the password doesn't get grabbed.

So basically http://userid:password@www.anywhere.com/ completely bypasses the method and it's not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a short description of this authentication way [here](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/user-pass-url.html), for more details you'll have to look for the proper standard describing URL.

URL sample in case the page is not available later: `ftp://username:password@hostname/`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

> If the delegate does not implement this method the default
>   implementation is used. **If a valid credential for the request is**
>    **provided as part of the URL**, or is available from the
>   NSURLCredentialStorage **the [challenge sender] is sent a
>   ***useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:* with the credential**. If the
>   challenge has no credential or the credentials fail to authorize
>   access, then continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: is
>   sent to [challenge sender] instead.

Comment: Yea, I tried that before, but that's not the right format. Doing it like that seems to bypass the authentication method all together and log me in. I am guessing it is also not secure.

Comment: @Alan Shih I don't know where this is used at `AFNetworking`. But if you try this line of code against `[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://username:password@hostname/"]` you will get `password` returned. Understanding `AFNetworking` architecture is a little harder than analyzing a single line, e.g. `username:password` part might be added by the framework itself in some cases.

Comment: It is part of the NSURLCONnection delegate method - 
`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` Yea... I am trying to get authentication working.

Comment: @Alan Shih see the edit for added Apple reference quote, you might want to look through the commits history or AFNetworking discussion at GitHub if you are interested in it.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially - some URLs are structured with a contained UserName and password

```
http://userid:password@www.anywhere.com/
```

If you pass a URL with this format to the function it will return the password part of the URL if it is in the correct format, or an empty string `(CFSTR(""))` if it is not.

In the same way you can get the userid with the `CFURLCopyUserName` function.

Comment: Yea I have tried that, but it seems to bypass the authentication method alltogether. It is not going into the method that has that line of code in the framework.